# Pandas More Efficient way to filter groups that contain a null field?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to filter out groups in pandas that contain a null field. I'm doing this through iterating over all the groups as such.

```
for _, g in df.groupby(['name', 'group']):
     if not (g['val'].isnull()).any()
         #Do more stuff with group, as none of its records are null
```

This is quite inefficient however, and has become the central bottleneck for my code. Is there any way to represent this behavior without the need for iterating over each group, this dataframe is quite large.

Edit:

This behavior wouldn't be accomplished by simply removing the null records before the groupby. The groupby serves to distinguish what an acceptable group is. If you remove all the null records beforehand, then all groups will pass, which is not desired.

Basically I'm trying to solve this, *for each group, make sure that it doesn't contain a null record, if it does **discard the whole group, not just the record itself***

Edit 2:

Here's a more concrete example, granted it isn't at the size for performance to be of concern.

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'name': 'alpha', 'group': 1, 'val': 100}, {'name': 'alpha', 'group': 1, 'val': numpy.nan},
                      {'name': 'alpha', 'group': 1, 'val': 50}, {'name': 'beta', 'group': 1, 'val': 20}, {'name': 'beta', 'group': 1, 'val': 40},
                      {'name': 'beta', 'group': 2, 'val': numpy.nan}, {'name': 'beta', 'group': 2, 'val': 120}])
print df

   group   name    val
0      1  alpha  100.0
1      1  alpha    NaN
2      1  alpha   50.0
3      1   beta   20.0
4      1   beta   40.0
5      2   beta    NaN
6      2   beta  120.0

for _, g in df.groupby(['name', 'group']):
    if not (g['val'].isnull()).any():
        print g

   group  name   val
3      1  beta  20.0
4      1  beta  40.0
```

Comment: I think it boils down to what you are trying to acomplish in the `if` statement. It might be possible to rewrite it without the `groupby` and `if` which could be more efficient.

Comment: Also `if not (g['val'].isnull()).any()` can be rewritten as `if (g['val'].notnull()).all()` for more clarity (Altough I guess it's a matter of preference :) )

Comment: @RobinNemeth I think the conversation with piRSquared is alluding to a solution that removes the work from the groupby statement.

Comment: What are you doing with the groups that pass the filter? It might be worthwile to add a column serving as an indicator whether the group is acceptable or not and apply a vectorized operation only on the acceptable rows

Comment: @RobinNemeth The operations after the filter would be rather difficult to properly vectorize. However, this filter should filter down the set to about 0.5% of its original size. So these operations, don't do much to impact the overall performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`filter` within the `groupby`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) context takes a `callable` that returns a `bool` that determines if the group will be included or not.  I'd do it this way:

```
# Truth values across whole grouped dataframe on what pandas thinks is null
#                                                \ ______
#                                                /        \
df.groupby(['name', 'group']).filter(lambda df: df.notnull().values.all())
#                                                             \________/
#                                                             /
# Letting numpy determine if everything in the 2-D array is True
```

Comment: Would this give a noticeable speedup though? The filter method would still iterate each group and apply a logical dataframe operation.

However, it is cleaner. Didn't know such a method was associated with a groupby object.

Comment: @jab that's a fair question.. provide some data and I'll tell you.  Also, I don't know what you are doing in the rest of the loop.  Those things might be able to be performed in a vectorized way or not.  You've provided very little information.

Comment: I tried adding an example (a much simplified version), I wouldn't concern the rest of the loop body, as the filtered result would only be around 0.5% the size of the original.

Comment: As in, there exists a null value in a group about 95% of time.

Comment: Perhaps a solution that would involve getting the original group sizes, filtering out all `nan` records, and then finally getting the new group sizes (then comparing the sizes of old and new) would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate. Just use df.isnull(). It will return a DataFrame of boolean values.